# Восстановление позиции RecyclerView при возврате

Tags: android, java

Как можно узнать, в какой позиции был элемент в `RecycleView` или первый видимый элемент, и когда пользователь вернется обратно к этому списку, вернуть положение на то же место?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Parcelable mLayoutManagerState;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

    state.putParcelable("StoreRecyclerView", recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state); 

    mLayoutManagerState = state.getParcelable("StoreRecyclerView");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 

    if (mLayoutManagerState != null) {
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mLayoutManagerState);
    }        
}
```