# ListView, запомнить/восстановить положение скрола

Tags: java, android, listview

Как запомнить положение скрола ListView и восстановить их при следующем возврате на активити с ним?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Лично я считаю наиболее оптимальным следующий способ (подходит для поворотов устройства и переходов по стеку в пределах одного запуска приложения):

```
Parcelable state;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
    if(state != null) {
        listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {    
    state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
    super.onPause();
}
```

То есть мы используем методы сохранения и востановления состояния списка, которые специально предназаначены для этого.

Если требуется долгосрочное хранение (например, запомнить позицию после выхода из приложения), то можно использовать следующий способ:

```
SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

 pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 mList.setSelectionFromTop(pref.getInt("index",0), pref.getInt("top",0));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {   

    int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = mList.getChildAt(0);
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - mList.getPaddingTop());

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putInt("index", index);
    edit.putInt("top", top);
    edit.apply();

    super.onPause();
}
```

То есть, здесь мы перед выходом из активити получаем позицию, в которой находится `ListView` и сохраняем ее в `SharedPrefrences` для долгосрочного хранения, затем восстанавливаем при (пере-)запуске активити сохраненную позицию в списке.

[Другие варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3014089) решения enSO

Comment: А есть альтернатива onRestoreInstanceState для RecyclerView?

Comment: @Artsait Есть [альтернатива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468811/177345) для RecyclerView