# Как сохранить положения скролла RecyclerView при переходе из дочернего активити?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть MainActivity, в нем RecyclerView. По клику на элемент в этом списке открывается новое активити.

Предположим я скролю список вниз. И на экране видна N-ная позиция элемента списка. Кликаю по этому элементу. Открывается новое активити. Далее нажимаю назад. И список отображается с 1-ой позиции, а не с N-ной. Как сохранить это текущее положение?

Comment: А у Вас случайно список заполняется не в `onStart()`? Или в `onCreate()` все заполнение происходит?

Comment: @Vladimir Parfenov в onCreate()

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468811/177345

Comment: Не успел эту ссылку прислать)

Comment: Спасибо Вам!!!;)

Comment: @pavlofff нет проблем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За позиционирование элементов в `RecyclerView` отвечает `LayoutManager`, состояние которого и требуется сохранить.

У класса `LayoutManager` есть метод [`onSaveInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#onSaveInstanceState()), который возвращает объект, характеризующий текущее состояние `LayoutManager`, причем данный объект реализует интерфейс `Parcelable`, следовательно, этот объект можно поместить в `Bundle`.

Также, у класса `LayoutManager` есть метод [`onRestoreInstanceState(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable)), с помощью которого можно восстановить состояние `LayoutManager`.

Пример:

Сохранение состояния:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(LAYOUT_MANAGER_KEY, mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
}
```

Восстановление состояния:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Parcelable recyclerViewLayoutState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LAYOUT_MANAGER_KEY);
    mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewLayoutState);
}
```

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста как можно сохранить состояние в SharedPreferences?