# RecyclerView - сохранить позицию скролла во фрагменте при повороте

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Здравствуйте, направьте пожалуйста на верный путь. На данный момент есть код который не работает:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    View v = adslist.getChildAt(0);
    top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
    index = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    outState.putInt("index", index);
    outState.putInt("top", top);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setScrollPosition(savedInstanceState); 
}


public void setScrollPosition(Bundle scrollState) {
    if (scrollState != null) {
        top = scrollState.getInt("top", 0);
        index = scrollState.getInt("index", -1);
    }
}
```

С `ListView` всё работает, а вот с `recycler` не получается.

Дополнение:

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, savedInstanceState.toString()); // null
    listState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(SCROOLL_TAG);
}
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                     java.lang.NullPointerException
                     at com.example.admin.vp.ads.AdsView.onViewStateRestored(AdsView.java:101)
                     at android.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:612)
                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:905)
                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
                     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
                     ......
```

Comment: ресайклер и так сохраняет своё состояние. в разметке xml id у ресайклера есть?

Comment: `id` есть в разметке

Comment: Но всё же фрагмент пересоздаётся и позиция сбрасывается

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/393542/177345

Comment: @pavlofff ну ведь из сути вопроса, мне нужно сохранить позицию скролла именно во фрагменте

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо вам огромное :) Добавьте пожалуйста ответ, я приму его как верное решение. Идеально работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой выход как по мне, добавить в файл Манифест в ту активити, где лежит фрагмент, следующую строку:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Соответственно, при повороте экрана, активити не будет создаваться заново, следовательно и фрагмент не поменяет свои свойства.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую реализовать и вашу подсказку.

Comment: Работает тоже очень даже не плохо) в чём разница тога между сэмплом и `"android:configChanges"`?

Comment: @sergei1094 если честно - без понятия :) Никогда сэмпл не юзал. Просто знаю, что если прописать в манифесте всего лишь мою одну строку, то активити пересоздаваться не будет, но будет отображаться в зависимости от ориентации устройства. Мне это помогло в том случае, когда я воспроизводил видео в своем проекте :) По крайней мере для моих задач этого было достаточно.

Comment: В принципе для моих задач это тоже более чем достаточно) Приму ваш ответ как верный и полезный. Сэмпл - это слишком много лишнего кода )

Comment: Спасибо :) но у меня не отображается галочка, что вы указали мой ответ верным ;)

Answer (score 2):

в вашем случае достаточно вызвать `mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(index)` внутри вашего `setScrollPosition(Bundle scrollState)`

в документации описано:

> ```
> * RecyclerView does not implement scrolling logic, rather forwards the call to
> * {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager#scrollToPosition(int)}
> ```

Comment: Мне вызывать в `onCreate(..)`?

Comment: если вы хотите  чтобы этот код срабатывал при повороте экрана, то да в onCreate()

Comment: А как быть с установкой позиции с точностью до пикселя? Ваш ответ помог сохранить позицию по `index` а `top`?

Comment: @sergei1094 RecyclerView не поддерживает такое

Comment: И даже костылей никаких не придумать? Я не думаю что в RecyclerView есть такой недостаток. Как то же всё равно должно это реализовываться

Comment: @sergei1094 смотрите ссылку на другой вопрос (и решение) в комментариях под вашим вопросом

Comment: @pavlofff я дополнил свой вопрос. В методе `onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState)` я получаю исключение `FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.NullPointerException`