# Как при повороте экрана вернуть RecyclerView в ту позицию, до которой долистал пользователь?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-sdk

Есть `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`, у которого количество колонок задаётся в зависимости от ширины экрана и, соответственно, не равно в портретной и альбомной ориентации. Нужно, чтобы долистав до определённого места и перевернув экран пользователь бы начал листать с того места, где остановился.

Предполагаю, что нужно перед уничтожением активности сохранить позицию элемента, до которого долистали, и в `onCreate()` задать её `RecyclerView`. Но как бы это сделать? Не особо разбирался, но просто сохранить и задать `State` не помогает.

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` и `onRestoreInstanceState` вам в помощь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468811/177345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень емкий и удобный вариант.

```
Parcelable mLayoutManagerState;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

    state.putParcelable("StoreRecyclerView", recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state); 

    mLayoutManagerState = state.getParcelable("StoreRecyclerView");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 

    if (mLayoutManagerState != null) {
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mLayoutManagerState);
    }        
}
```

*PS.:
Этот код был давно опубликован pavlofff [Восстановление позиции RecyclerView при возврате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468811/177345). Но так как тот вопрос закрыт и может быть удален, то решил перепостить. Дабы не потерять полезный код.*